# Normalizr normalize nested data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, normalizr

I have a nested data which looks like this:

```
{
  components: [
    guid: "cms-container/c154c79596b3af6326966b0c994e2a934",
    regions: [{
      guid :"r1c154c79596b3af6326966b0c994e2a934",
      components: [{ 
          guid: "cms-markupfile/owg-header.html" },
        { guid: "cms-navmenu/n1503636374400" },
        { guid: "cms-container/c50c451ba72e4b4edab979cf477129215",
          regions: [{
            guid: "r1c50c451ba72e4b4edab979cf477129215",
            components: [{
              guid:"cms-serie/serieDetailRenderer"
            }]
          }]
        },
      ]
    }]
  ]
}
```

As you can see this is a nested structure with arbitrary nesting.
That is, in the components array there can be also an array of region in which, in turn, there can be another components array.

I'm trying to bring this structure to a flat form with normalizr but so far without result. I would be grateful for the help in solving this problem.

Comment: It'd be valuable to show what you've got so far, even if it's not working quite right yet. This will help people tailor their answers to you. Even just the shape of what you need the normalised data to look like would be helpful.

Comment: This may require you tweak the process and merge strategies.

This is explained in more detail here: https://medium.com/@JustinTRoss/normalizing-data-into-relational-redux-state-with-normalizr-47e7020dd3c1

Answer (score 0):

I would try something as simple as that :

```
import { schema } from 'normalizr'

const schemas = {
    component: new schema.Entity('components'),
    region: new schema.Entity('regions')
}

schemas.component.define({
    regions: [schemas.region]
})
schemas.region.define({
    components: [schemas.component]
})
```

I'm afraid of circular references, but it's worth trying.
If it's not working can you supply what you've done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the answer might be useful to someone.
If I understand correctly, each component contains unique identifier (guid) and possibly an array of regions, while each region contains unique identifier (guid) and possibly an array of components. If that is the case, you are missing a couple of `{}` inside the outermost components array. Instead of

```
 {
    components: [
```

you should write

```
{
components: [{
```

And at the end, instead of

```
  ]
}
```

you should write

```
 }]
}
```

Now, suppose my understanding of your data is correct, and suppose you make correction as suggested, your normalizr schema should look as folowing:

```
import { schema, normalize } from 'normalizr'

const regionSchema = new schema.Entity(
    'regions', 
    { components: [ componentSchema ] }, 
    { idAttribute: 'guid' }
)

const componentSchema = new schema.Entity(
    'components', 
    { regions: [ regionSchema ] }, 
    { idAttribute: 'guid' }
)
```

and you should normalize your data like this

```
let data = [{
    guid: "cms-container/c154c79596b3af6326966b0c994e2a934",
    regions: [{
      guid :"r1c154c79596b3af6326966b0c994e2a934",
      components: [{ 
          guid: "cms-markupfile/owg-header.html" },
        { guid: "cms-navmenu/n1503636374400" },
        { guid: "cms-container/c50c451ba72e4b4edab979cf477129215",
          regions: [{
            guid: "r1c50c451ba72e4b4edab979cf477129215",
            components: [{
              guid:"cms-serie/serieDetailRenderer"
            }]
          }]
        },
      ]
    }]
  }]

let normalizedData = normalize(data, [componentSchema])
```